# Loop a function which includes an Ajax Call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, synchronous

Below `test()` function will be called 6 times inside a loop by `loopTheTest()`.

I want these 6 calls to be run synchronously.

I know `async:false` is a bad practice, and I couldn't find a clear solution on how to achieve this.

I checked topics `promises` and `async-await`, but couldn't apply them to below case (due to my lack of knowledge).

**P.S:** I'am not looking for a recursive solution.

```
function loopTheTest(){

     var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

     for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
         test(cars[i]);
     }
}
function test(car){
    //Some Codes
    //AJAX POST REQUEST
    //Some Codes
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to handle arrays on server side to have to call it only once with all values. Else you can always make your requests synchronous by passing `false` as third parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Promise.all(cars.map(test)).then(function(arrayOfResults) { /* do something with the results */ });

Answer (score 1):

With async/await and using [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) to have a 'real' fetch(), you can get your result with a **for/of loop** :

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');

const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/";

async function test(car,i){
    const result = await fetch(url+(i+1));
    const descr = await result.json();
    return cars[i] + " " + descr.title;
}

async function loopTheTest() {
    for (const [i, car] of cars.entries()) {
      let res = await test(car,i);
      console.log(`Received test ${i + 1}:`, res);
    }
    console.log(' Finish !!!');
  }

loopTheTest();
```

You get :

```
Received test 1: BMW quidem molestiae enim
Received test 2: Volvo sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa
Received test 3: Saab omnis laborum odio
Received test 4: Ford non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio
Received test 5: Fiat eaque aut omnis a
Received test 6: Audi natus impedit quibusdam illo est
 Finish !
```

Comment: What is isomorphic-fetch? . And can you implement above code on jsfiddle ? I couldn't make it work.

Comment: it's just in case you are executing that in nodeJS (server side).

Comment: otherwise replace jsonplaceholder with your server url to avoid CORS issues

Comment: I tried to implement your code but I guess I am missing something. Can you check my other thread with my real codes ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219048/async-await-how-to-implement-javascript-async-await-in-a-recursive-ajax-functi

Answer (score 0):

When you loop with Ajax, call the next Ajax in the success:

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
cnt = 0;

function test() {
  if (cnt >= cars.length) return; // stop

  var car = cars[cnt];
  fetch("someprocess?car=" + car)
    .then(function(data) {
      showFunction(data);
      cnt++;
      test();
    })
}
test()
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case, I am not looking for a recursive solution. I need a solution including a for loop. I simplified my code before posting to stackoverflow.

Comment: I wish I was that young. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to run sequentially, something like this should work

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
async function test() {
    for (let index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
        const data = await fetch("someprocess?car=" + cars[index])
        // do whatever you want to do with the response data here
    }
}
```