# Async/Await - How to implement Javascript Async-Await in a recursive Ajax function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

I have two functions.

I call `trendyolStocksUpdate()` function several times with a loop inside `syncTrendyolOFFStocks()` function.

I used `async/await` but `trendyolStocksUpdate()` function is not called sequentially. It runs simultaneously.

What is wrong with my code ?

**Below are the two functions:**

```
async function syncTrendyolOFFStocks(){

  //This function sends "out of stock products" one by one
  //to trendyolStocksUpdate function, so they their quantity will be initalized to 0
  //For example, T-Shirt XL Yellow, and T-Shirt XXL Red are sent.

  for(var product in all){
    var colors = all[product];
    for(var singleColor in colors[0]){
      var size = colors[0][singleColor];
      for(var index in size){
        var singleSize = size[index];
        await trendyolStocksUpdate(0,"",allProducts[product],singleSize,singleColor,0);
      }
    }
  }
}


async function trendyolStocksUpdate(stockCount,price,product,size,color,rowCount){

  //This function sends given Product Variation to trendyolUpdateStock.php with jQuery.ajax
  //recursively. 1000 product's quantity are equalized to 0, once at a time.

  dataObj = {
    rowCount: rowCount,
    product: product,
    size:size,
    color:color,
    stockCount: stockCount,
  };

  if(price != ""){
    dataObj["price"] = price;
  }

  await jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/wp-content/plugins/promc/templates/trendyolUpdateStock.php",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dataObj,
         success: function(data)
         {

           if(data.numberOfRows == 1000)
           {
              rowCount = rowCount + 1000;
              trendyolStocksUpdate(stockCount,price,product,size,color,rowCount);
           }
           else
           {
             jQuery("#trendyolMonitor").append("<h3>Completed!</h3>");
             rowCount = 0;
           }
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
         {
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `jQuery.ajax()` doesn't return a Promise, so the `await` does nothing here, since it'll simply resolve immediately if used on something that isn't a Promise. You need to either use `fetch()` instead, or wrap the jQuery.ajax call in a Promise.

Comment: @ChrisG it's not a promise but it _is_ [thenable](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). `await` will not simply resolve immediately.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ah, I did check the docs again to make sure but didn't read far enough :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `trendyolStocksUpdate(stockCount,price,product,size,color,rowCount);` inside of the success function it’s not being awaited. So the function will return before the recursive call is completed.

Instead of using a success function, you could put that logic in after the awaited ajax call.

```js
async function trendyolStocksUpdate(stockCount,price,product,size,color,rowCount){
  //This function sends given Product Variation to trendyolUpdateStock.php with jQuery.ajax
  //recursively. 1000 product's quantity are equalized to 0, once at a time.

  dataObj = {
    rowCount: rowCount,
    product: product,
    size:size,
    color:color,
    stockCount: stockCount,
  };

  if(price != ""){
    dataObj["price"] = price;
  }

  try {
    const data = await jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-content/plugins/promc/templates/trendyolUpdateStock.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: dataObj
    });
    if(data.numberOfRows == 1000)
    {
      rowCount = rowCount + 1000;
      await trendyolStocksUpdate(stockCount,price,product,size,color,rowCount);
    }
    else
    {
      jQuery("#trendyolMonitor").append("<h3>Completed!</h3>");
      rowCount = 0;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error stuff…
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `const data = await jQuery.ajax({ /* ... */ }); if (data.numberOfRows == 1000) ...`

Comment: @alexander, can you please include what is inside /*...*/ . ? ..... I mean should I remove success function and error function ?

Comment: Yes. That is better!

Comment: @HOY is "Instead of using a success function" not clear enough?

Comment: @HOY I have updated the code snippet to be more complete and better.

Comment: @Alexander don't catch the error. Errors in API functions should propagate to the caller.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts regarding "Errors in API functions should propagate to the caller." can you give me a google page, to better understand what you mean.

Comment: @HOY Get rid of the try/catch in trendyolStocksUpdate, and instead put a try/catch around wherever you call syncTrendyolOFFStocks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if u have await the **jQuery Ajax is still asynchronous and has its own callback function.** Try setting async as false in jQuery Ajax options.

```
async: false
```

**This is not recommended as it defeats whole purpose of Ajax.** But your question seems more towards synchronous api calls, so this might do the trick for you..

Answer (score -1):

Your `trendyolStocksUpdate` function needs to return a Promise for this to work properly.

Comment: _All_ [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions return a Promise. This doesn't answer the question.